# How to properly develop/build Lucee core?

Tags: java, maven, lucee

I am having a hard time figuring how to develop the [Lucee](https://github.com/lucee/Lucee) core properly/quickly. According to the [documentation](http://docs.lucee.org/guides/working-with-source/build-from-source.html) it says I can use Maven/Ant to build the source, I chose Maven. However this process takes a while to complete and the method I am using for testing my changes to the core files takes a while.

My current process is very inefficient and I want to speed it up. Basically what I have done is cloned the master branch and imported the two projects “core” and “loader” into Eclipse. After editing a file to test my changes I will run “mvn clean install” which takes several minutes (with tests disabled) and eventually spits out a JAR. I then copy this JAR into the “tomcat/lib/ext” directory and restart tomcat. After tomcat starts up I am able to see if my changes were successful or not.

As you can see this process is very slow and probably not the way it is intended to be done.

I am almost certain this is not the way the Lucee core is not supposed to be developed because it is slow and cumbersome. Is there a certain setup I can do inside of Eclipse  or change a change to the way I am building it to help greatly speed up development?

I have [cross-posted this question to the Lucee forum](https://dev.lucee.org/t/development-environment-for-developing-the-lucee-core-loader/3863) already but I am still waiting on a response.

Comment: I haven't worked with lucee, but in general I always try to develop unit tests to cover my changes, so I don't need to compile/install whole project, but run test directly from eclipse, which is usually faster